# How define usedCommandrecently4

Tags: discord.js

```
case 'play':

    if(usedCommandRecently4.has(message.author.id)){
        message.reply("Your using this command to fast!");
    } else{
        function play(connection, message){
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

            server.queue.shift();

            message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n Adding song to queue!");

            server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                if(server.queue[0]){
                    play(connection, message);
                }else {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            })
        }

        if(!args[1]){
            message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n you need to provide a link!!");
            return;
        }

        if(!message.member.voice.channel){
            message.channel.send("``Music Bot v1.2`` \n You must be in a voice channel to play music!");
            return;
        }

        if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
            queue: []
        }

        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        server.queue.push(args[1]);

        if(!message.guild.voiceConnection)message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
            server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
            play(connection, message);

        })

        usedCommandRecently4.add(message.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
            usedCommandRecently4.delete(message.author.id)
        }, 10000);
    }

break;
```

I asked here for a solution because i get a error, the error was `connectio.playStream` is not a function but now is fixed so anyways, but now i get another error and i dont know how to define `usedCommandRecently4` the code below me is the code that the person who helped me gave me.

Comment: usedCommandRecently4 should be a list or collection of some sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `usedCommandRecently4` as a set at the top of your code.
`Set` objects are collections of values which you can add to or remove from.

```
const usedCommandRecently4 = new Set();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set